# Identify original text, assembled code and machine code in QtSPIM simulator

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim, pcspim

I am using QtSPIM to learn assembly language.
[An screenshot of PC SPIM text segment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLATV.png)

How can I identify which part of this line is the original text, assembled code and machine code?
What are the major difference between assembled code and machine code?

I have used ChatGPT and it gives me the same answer as below:
Assembled Version (Machine Code): 0x8fa40000
Machine Code Version (Hexadecimal): 0x8fa40000

Comment: Original text is presumably the last part: `lw $a0, 0($sp)`. Assembled is the middle part `lw $4, 0($29)`. Machine code is as ChatGPT said the `0x8fa40000`. The `00400000` at the front is the address.

Comment: Keep in mind that ChatGPT is *very* unreliable for assembly languages specifically.  Use a real assembler like GAS or Clang.  https://godbolt.org/ can probably be coaxed into assembling MIPS code to binary, although maybe only with inline asm in C (perhaps at global scope).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line is one 32-bit machine code instruction.

The part in `[]`s is the memory address for the insrtuction.

After is a hex value of the instruction encoding, which we would call the machine code instruction.

Following is a disassembly of that instruction.

And finally, the source code assembly.